# Use dplyr's summarise and summarise_each together?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to apply `dplyr::summarise` and `dplyr::summarise_each` at the same time for a grouped data frame. Is it possible?

My data looks like this:

```r
mydf <- data.frame(
    id = c(rep(1,2), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 4)), 
    amount = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,5)), 
    type1 = c(rep(1, 2), rep(0, 7)),
    type2 = c(rep(0, 4), rep(1, 5))
)
mydf
#  id amount type1 type2
#1  1      1     1     0
#2  1      1     1     0
#3  2      1     0     0
#4  2      1     0     0
#5  2      2     0     1
#6  3      2     0     1
#7  3      2     0     1
#8  3      2     0     1
#9  3      2     0     1
```

I would like to sum over `id` the `amount` variable and get the max for the `type` variables. I know I can do this as follows:

```r
mydf %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(amount = sum(amount), type1 = max(type1), type2 = max(type2))
```

However, I have a lot of `type` variables so I would prefer something like this (but with the sum of `amount` as well).

```r
mydf %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(max), matches("type"))
```

Comment: Interesting question. I wonder if you open for non-`dplyr` solutions.

Comment: `dplyr` might not allow for this. Then I should find a non-`dplyr` solution.

Comment: may be `unique(mydf %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(amount = sum(amount)) %>% mutate_each(funs(max), matches("type")))` ?

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar This is a good work around, thanks. If you post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar to keep the piping: `mydf %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(amount = sum(amount)) %>% mutate_each(funs(max), matches("type")) %>% unique`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>% 
     group_by(id) %>% 
     mutate(amount = sum(amount)) %>% 
     mutate_each(funs(max), matches("type")) %>%
     unique

#Source: local data table [3 x 4]

#  id amount type1 type2
#1  1      2     1     0
#2  2      4     0     1
#3  3      8     0     1
```

Or simply *as @HongOoi indicated*

```
mydf %>% 
     group_by(id) %>% 
     mutate(amount=sum(amount)) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(max))
```

Comment: You could also replace the combination of `mutate_each` and `unique` with `summarise_each` - `summarise_each(funs(max))` if summarizing all variables in the dataset or `summarise_each(funs(max), amount, matches("type"`))` if not.

Comment: Hmm, yes, when it gives wrong result on a `data.table` object, I've should have test this code before the `data.table` solution. Let me think of it

Comment: @DavidArenburg I know why you think the results are not ok. It is because  you are running your solution first (transforming `mydf` into a `data.table` then running @veerendra's solution. Do this: `as.data.frame(mydf) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(amount = sum(amount)) %>% mutate_each(funs(mean), matches("type")) %>% unique` to make sure that it is not a `data.table` and you will see that the result is exactly like yours.

Comment: @DavidArenburg we figured out the problem at the same time :) !  This is probably a  `dplyr` bug when interfacing with `data.table` or vice-versa.

Comment: You don't need to reload `dplyr` just the data itself.

Comment: You can simplify this to `mydf %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(amount=sum(amount)) %>% summarise_each(funs(max))`

Comment: @HongOoi this only works correctly for that mock data and that isn't a general solution.

Comment: @DavidArenburg the general solution would be for "I have a lot of type variables so I would prefer something like this (but with the sum of amount as well)". In this case, what I noted works just fine, although you may need to select the variables in the `summarise_each` call.

Comment: @HongOoi this is exactly what I meant. Without the `matches("type")` you will be operating over all the columns. In some cases you may have `character` columns which will work fine with `unique`, but not with lets say `mean` and you'll get an error

Comment: @DavidArenburg in general, if you're going to use summarise_all, it's probably a good idea to do a variable selection at some point. Bringing character data into the equation is neither here nor there, since summarising it is rarely sensible.

Comment: @HongOoi It seems like you keep saying "variable selection" but your proposed code doesn't do that, so I'm really confused regarding what you are trying to say.

Comment: @DavidArenburg is it so hard to mentally add a `select(amount, matches("type")` to the chain?

Comment: @HongOoi than it won't be any better than just use `unique`, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidArenburg if you want, you can also fold the select into the summarise_all. If you want to summarise a dataset, then use summarise[_all], that's what it's for.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure regarding the idiomatic way using `dplyr`, but this is pretty idiomatic using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, c(amount = sum(amount), 
                lapply(.SD[, grep("type", names(mydf), value = TRUE), with = FALSE], max)),
            by = id]
#    id amount type1 type2
# 1:  1      2     1     0
# 2:  2      4     0     1
# 3:  3      8     0     1
```

---

Basically, we are combining both operation using `c`, while `lapply(.SD, max)` stands for `mutate_each` in `dplyr` and `matches` is just a wrapper for `grep` (as clearly shown [in the source code](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-utils.R#L33-L37)). `with = FALSE` is for standard evaluation of column names within a `data.table` or `.SD` parent frame (which stands for **S**ub**D**ata).

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach with `dplyr` could be:

```
mydf %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate_each('sum', amount) %>%
  mutate_each('max', matches("type")) %>%
  summarise_each('first', amount, matches("type"))
```

This has the benefit of applying only one aggregate function to each column that Veerendra Gadekar's original answer had. It comes handy if we need `sd` or similar in place of `max`, Hong Ooi's solution would break in such case. It would also break if there are character columns. Third advantage is that it drops the columns that are not part of the computation.

See also [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33702470/1916449).