# Aggregate sum and mean in R with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

My data frame has two columns that are used as a grouping key, 17 columns that need to be summed in each group, and one column that should be averaged instead. Let me illustrate this on a different data frame, `diamonds` from `ggplot2`.

I know I could do it like this:

```
ddply(diamonds, ~cut, summarise, x=sum(x), y=sum(y), z=sum(z), price=mean(price))
```

But while it is reasonable for 3 columns, it is unacceptable for 17 of them.

When researching this, I found the `colwise` function, but the best I came up with is this:

```
cbind(ddply(diamonds, ~cut, colwise(sum, 7:9)), price=ddply(diamonds, ~cut, summarise, mean(price))[,2])
```

Is there a possibility to improve this even further? I would like to do it in a more straightforward way, something like (imaginary commands):

```
ddply(diamonds, ~cut, colwise(sum, 7:9), price=mean(price))
```

or:

```
ddply(diamonds, ~cut, colwise(sum, 7:9), colwise(mean, ~price))
```

To sum up:

- I don't want to have to type all 17 columns explicitly, like the first example does with `x`, `y`, and `z`.
- Ideally, I would like to do it with a single call to `ddply`, without resorting to `cbind` (or similar functions), as in the second example.

For reference, the result I expect is 5 rows and 5 columns:

```
        cut         x         y        z    price
1      Fair  10057.50   9954.07  6412.26 4358.758
2      Good  28645.08  28703.75 17855.42 3928.864
3 Very Good  69359.09  69713.45 43009.52 3981.760
4   Premium  82385.88  81985.82 50297.49 4584.258
5     Ideal 118691.07 118963.24 73304.61 3457.542
```

Comment: If you are using `dplyr`, perhaps `diamonds %>% group_by(cut) %>% mutate(MeanPrice=mean(price)) %>% mutate_each(funs(sum), 7:9) %>% select(c(2,7:11)) %>% unique()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antoher solution using `dplyr`. First you apply both aggregate functions on every variable you want to be aggregated. Of the resulting variables you select only the desired function/variable combination.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

diamonds %>%
    group_by(cut) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(sum, mean), x:z, price) %>%
    select(cut, matches("[xyz]_sum"), price_mean)
```

Comment: Are you then left with constructing a matches expression that requires that the user type all 17 columns explicitly ...  I suppose you can shortcut it with a text parsing expression on the colnames from within a range ...?

Comment: @rpierce select function of dplyr provides a lot of possibilities for selecting variables. The OP has to find a way to specify the variables that need to be aggregated. But this is necessary with all the solution discussed here.

Comment: Technically I suppose, anything that used a ranged selector seemed a bit more clean in terms of meeting their request about not needing to specify each column directly.  Regardless, your solution is quite a bit faster than the others!

Answer (score 12):

I would like to suggest `data.table` solutions for this. You can easily predefine the columns you want operate either by position or by names and then reuse the same code no matter how many column you want to operate on.

*Predifine column names*

```
Sums <- 7:9
Means <- "price"
```

*Run the code*

```
library(data.table)
data.table(diamonds)[, c(lapply(.SD[, Sums, with = FALSE], sum),
                         lapply(.SD[, Means, with = FALSE], mean))
                     , by = cut]

#          cut         x         y        z    price
# 1:     Ideal 118691.07 118963.24 73304.61 3457.542
# 2:   Premium  82385.88  81985.82 50297.49 4584.258
# 3:      Good  28645.08  28703.75 17855.42 3928.864
# 4: Very Good  69359.09  69713.45 43009.52 3981.760
# 5:      Fair  10057.50   9954.07  6412.26 4358.758
```

For your specific example, this could simplified to just

```
data.table(diamonds)[, c(lapply(.SD[, 7:9, with = FALSE], sum), pe = mean(price)), by = cut]
#          cut         x         y        z       pe
# 1:     Ideal 118691.07 118963.24 73304.61 3457.542
# 2:   Premium  82385.88  81985.82 50297.49 4584.258
# 3:      Good  28645.08  28703.75 17855.42 3928.864
# 4: Very Good  69359.09  69713.45 43009.52 3981.760
# 5:      Fair  10057.50   9954.07  6412.26 4358.758
```

Answer (score 5):

Yet another approach (in my opinion easier to read) for your particular case (`mean = sum/n`!)

```
nCut <- ddply(diamonds, ~cut, nrow)
res <- ddply(diamonds, ~cut, colwise(sum, 6:9))
res$price <- res$price/nCut$V1
```

or the more generic,

```
do.call(merge, 
    lapply(c(colwise(sum, 7:9), colwise(mean, 6)), 
           function(cw) ddply(diamonds, ~cut, cw)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to throw in another solution:

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
trans <- list(mean = 8:10, sum = 7)

makeList <- function(inL, mdat = diamonds, by = ~cut) {
   colN <- names(mdat)
   args <- unlist(llply(names(inL), function(n) {
      llply(inL[[n]], function(x) {
         ret <- list(call(n, as.symbol(colN[[x]])))
         names(ret) <- paste(n, colN[[x]], sep = ".")
         ret
      })
   }))
   args$.data <- as.symbol(deparse(substitute(mdat)))
   args$.variables <- by
   args$.fun <- as.symbol("summarise")
   args
}

do.call(ddply, makeList(trans))
#         cut   mean.x   mean.y   mean.z sum.price
# 1      Fair 6.246894 6.182652 3.982770   7017600
# 2      Good 5.838785 5.850744 3.639507  19275009
# 3 Very Good 5.740696 5.770026 3.559801  48107623
# 4   Premium 5.973887 5.944879 3.647124  63221498
# 5     Ideal 5.507451 5.520080 3.401448  74513487
```

The idea is that the function `makeList` creates an argument list for `ddply`. In this way you can quite easily add terms to the list (as `function.name = column.indices`) and `ddply` will work as expected:

```
trans <- c(trans, sd = list(9:10))
do.call(ddply, makeList(trans))
#         cut   mean.x   mean.y   mean.z sum.price      sd.y      sd.z
# 1      Fair 6.246894 6.182652 3.982770   7017600 0.9563804 0.6516384
# 2      Good 5.838785 5.850744 3.639507  19275009 1.0515353 0.6548925
# 3 Very Good 5.740696 5.770026 3.559801  48107623 1.1029236 0.7302281
# 4   Premium 5.973887 5.944879 3.647124  63221498 1.2597511 0.7311610
# 5     Ideal 5.507451 5.520080 3.401448  74513487 1.0744953 0.6576481
```

Answer (score 2):

It uses `dplyr`, but I believe this will accomplish the specified aim completely in reasonably easy to read syntax:

```
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  select(x:z) %>%
  summarize_each(funs(sum)) %>%
  merge(diamonds %>%
          group_by(cut) %>%
          summarize(price = mean(price))
        ,by = "cut")
```

The only "trick" is that there is a piped expression inside of the merge that handles the calculation of the mean price separately from the calculation of sums.

I benchmarked this solution against the solution provided by @David Arenburg (using `data.table`) and @thothal (using `plyr` as requested by the question) with 5000 replications.  Here `data.table` came out slower than `plyr` and `dplyr`.  `dplyr` was faster than `plyr`.  One imagines that the benchmark results could change as a function of the number of columns, number of levels in the grouping factor, and particular functions applied.  For example, MarkusN submitted an answer after I did my initial benchmarks that is substantially faster than the previously submitted answers for the sample data.  He accomplishes this by calculating many summary statistics that aren't desired and then throwing them away... surely there must be a point at which the costs of that approach outweigh the advantages.

```
       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2 dataTable         5000 119.686    2.008   119.611    0.127          0         0
1     dplyr         5000  59.614    1.000    59.676    0.004          0         0
3      plyr         5000  68.505    1.149    68.493    0.064          0         0
?      MarkusN      5000  23.172    ?????    23.926        0          0         0
```

Certainly speed is not the only consideration.  In particular, dplyr and plyr are picky about the order in which they are loaded (plyr before dplyr) and have several functions that mask each other.

Comment: I guess that it is not so much about speed, but about convenience. If you need now to add another summarise function, you need to add another `merge` statement.

Comment: Relative to the data.table solution, this is certainly more verbose.  However, it is less verbose than the plyr solution.  I don't have any stake in regards to over which of these three solutions is 'best'.  I suspect the answer there would depend entirely on what someone was comfortable with and what they valued.  My only thought it was worth providing a dplyr solution that met the criteria of the question.

Comment: ... as as far as I can tell you'd only need to add another merge statement if you wanted to summarize using yet another disjoint set of variables.  There are quite possibly better ways to express this process in `dplyr`, that was only my stab.

Comment: compared to which `data.table` solution this was compared against? The first or the second? You are using `summarize_each` only once here because you assume there is only one column to run `mean` against, so you should compare against the second solution. Also, the data should be big enough. You should post the entire benchmark code here instead of just saying which is faster or not.

Comment: Sadly the benchmark code was ephemeral.  I'll post it next time; it seemed a bit verbose at the moment I was writing.  The data.table version I benchmarked was yours.

Comment: I've posted two different solutions, please reread my comment above again.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% what you are looking for but it might give you another idea on how to do it. Using `data.table` you can do something like this:

```
diamonds2[, .(c = sum(c), p = sum(p), ce = sum(ce), pe = mean(pe)), by = cut]
```

To shorten the code (what you tried to do with colwise), you probably have to write some functions to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: I wanted to use the `diamonds` dataset from `ggplot2` to make it reproducible, but was fooled by an old data frame lying around in my workspace, sorry. I've updated my question, and hopefully made it clear this time what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here's a solution based on `dplyr` and answers posted by [Veerendra Gadekar in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31815540/1916449) and [here by MarkusN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34061200/1916449).

In this particular case, it's possible to first apply `sum` to some of the columns and then `mean` to all columns of interest:

```
diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  mutate_each('sum', 8:10) %>%
  summarise_each('mean', 8:10, price)
```

This is possible, because `mean` won't change the calculated sums of columns `8:10` and will calculate the required mean of prices. But if we wanted to calculate standard deviation of prices instead of mean, this approach wouldn't work as columns `8:10` would all be 0.

A more general approach could be:

```
diamonds %>%
   group_by(cut) %>%
   mutate_each('sum', 8:10) %>%
   mutate_each('mean', price) %>%
   summarise_each('first', 8:10, price)
```

One may not be pleased by `summarise_each` repeating column specifications that were named earlier, but this seems like an elegant solution nonetheless.

It has the advantage over MarkusN's solution that it doesn't require matching newly created columns and doesn't change their names.

Solution by Veerendra Gadekar should end with `select(cut, 8:10, price) %>% arrange(cut)` in order to produce expected results (subset of columns, plus rows sorted by grouping key). Suggestion of Hong Ooi is similar to the first one here, but assumes there are no other columns.

Finally, it seems to be more legible and easy to understand than a `data.table` solution, like [the one proposed by David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33977175/1916449).