# How to combine two different dplyr summaries in a single command

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am trying to create a grouped summary that reports the number of records in each group and then also shows the means of a series of variables.

I can only work out how to do this as two separate summaries which I then join together. This works fine but I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do this?

```
dailyn<-daily %>% # this summarises n
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%

dailymeans <- daily %>% # this summarises the means
  group_by(type) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("d.")),funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%

dailysummary<-inner_join(dailyn,dailymeans) #this joins the two parts together
```

The data I'm working with is a dataframe like this:

```
daily<-data.frame(type=c("A","A","B","C","C","C"),
                  d.happy=c(1,5,3,7,2,4),
                  d.sad=c(5,3,6,3,1,2))
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in one call, by grouping, using mutate instead of summarize, and then use slice() to keep the first row of each type:

```
daily %>% group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("d.")),funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  slice(1L)
```

*Edit: It might be clearer how this works, in this modified example*

```
daily_summary <- daily %>% group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("d.")),funs("mean" = mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))

daily_summary
# Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
# Groups: type [3]
# 
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#    type d.happy d.sad     n d.happy_mean d.sad_mean
#  <fctr>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>
#1      A       1     5     2     3.000000          4
#2      A       5     3     2     3.000000          4
#3      B       3     6     1     3.000000          6
#4      C       7     3     3     4.333333          2
#5      C       2     1     3     4.333333          2
#6      C       4     2     3     4.333333          2

daily_summary %>% 
  slice(1L)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
# Groups: type [3]
# 
# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#    type d.happy d.sad     n d.happy_mean d.sad_mean
#  <fctr>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>        <dbl>      <dbl>
#1      A       1     5     2     3.000000          4
#2      B       3     6     1     3.000000          6
#3      C       7     3     3     4.333333          2
```

Comment: This works beautifully but I don't understand what it is doing. When you say 'keep the first row of each type' what is that? Why does the first row contain the means?

Comment: Using mutate instead of summarise ensures that we keep all data, and can do both your counting and mean calculations in the same dataframe. If you look at the result before using the slice() function, you will see that you have a grouped dataframe with three types, and you still have one row for each observation. `slice(1L)` then keeps the first row of each type (where type is the variable we grouped by).

Comment: To rephrase: When using mutate_at all rows end up containing the count and the mean (see my updated example), so it is not important that we keep the first row. It could be any row.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31815294/use-dplyrs-summarise-and-summarise-each-together), you can try:

```
daily %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("d.")),funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  unique
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: type [3]

    type  d.happy d.sad     n
  <fctr>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1      A 3.000000     4     2
2      B 3.000000     6     1
3      C 4.333333     2     3
```

Comment: This works fine for the example data I gave but my actual dataset has a whole bunch of extra columns. For some reason when the extra columns are present the grouping does not work.

Comment: Well, we can only work with the example data, sorry. Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)